# perl find max and record which one is it

Tags: perl, max

If i have three variables with integer and want to find which one is the largest one(not only the max integer), e.g if a is 3, b is 4 and c is 5, the I want to know c is the largest rather than return a 5 to me. How to achieve this or I should use

```
use List::Util

$d = max($a,$b,$c);
if($d == $a){}
elsif($d == $b){}
else{}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By using separate variables, you make pretty much anything impossible. Say you were using an array instead.

```
my @a = (3,4,5);

my $max_idx = 0;
for my $idx (1..$#a) {
   $max_idx = $idx
      if $a[$idx] > $a[$max_idx];
}

say $max_idx;
say $a[$max_idx];
```

Answer (score 1):

- Store the values in the array
- Loop over every INDEX in the array (hint: use `0..#$arrayName` construct)
- Keep, in a separate 2 variables, `$current_max_value` and `$current_max_index`
- When you find a value greater than `$current_max_value`, store it in `$current_max_value` and store current index in  `$current_max_index`
- When the loop finishes, you found your index of largest element (`$current_max_index`)

Answer (score 1):

This is easy using [PDL](http://pdl.perl.org/?docs=Ufunc&title=PDL%3a%3aUfunc#minmaximum), even for very large datasets.

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use PDL;

my $pdl = pdl( 3,4,5 );
my (undef, $max, undef, $max_index) = $pdl->minmaximum;

print "Max: $max (at index $max_index)\n";
```